# Expected number of rows of the full rank matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, finite-fields, computational-mathematics, computational-algebra

Let A be a m by n random matrix over finite fields F_q.
Suppose the rank of A is n.

How much does expected number of m? I think m maybe qlogq by bins and balls property

But I do not know exactly why.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying that $A$ is selected uniformly from the set of rank $n$ matrices?  Otherwise, how is $A$ selected?  Normally, $m$ and $n$ are fixed so we can't talk about the "expected value of $m$".

Comment: Should $m$ not be fixed? I don't get the question.

Comment: A is selected uniformly from the set of rank n matrices right.

Comment: @swain sorry for my ignorance, but how do you define an uniform probability on the set of rank $n$ matrices with arbitrarily many rows?

Comment: um.. I'm sorry. the problem may not be well defined. I think it seems like that random matrix

Comment: @swain if you don't define the randomness you can't get the expected value...

Comment: When I saw this problem, it maybe simple. but... TT

Comment: If it is an assignment, you should post the complete question.

Comment: Are you like selecting random row vectors and asking how many you need (on average) to get enough so that you get full rank? Or, do you begin with a random square matrix and ask for the expected value of its rank?

Comment: I'm talking about the first one.

Answer (score 2):

From the exchange in the comments, I gather that the question was intended to be how many rows of length $n$ you expect to add to a matrix over $\mathbb F_q$ if you successively add uniformly random rows (starting from none) until they span $\mathbb F_q^n$, that is until they form a matrix with full column rank.

This is a sort of coupon collector's problem, with modified probabilities, and the same approach yields the result.

For the first independent row, you have $q^n-1$ options, so the expected number of rows is $q^n/(q^n-1)$. For the next independent row, you have $q^n-q$ options, and generally, for the $(k+1)$-th independent row you have $q^n-q^k$ options. Thus the expected number of rows is

$$
q^n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac1{q^n-q^k}=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac1{1-q^{k-n}}\;.
$$